# Exception java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position (...). whit mariadb

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

The following code throws an exception to me, by using the mariadb manager, this with mysql not passed, allows me to do executeUpdate, but not executeQuery. The truth I have sought the solution and none is my case, because I am not committing any of those mistakes. Already reinstalled java and mariadb, still does not work.Thanks!

This is my code:

```
package Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class mainPruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/buscadorpersonas?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "2222";
        Connection conexion=null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        try {

            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

            ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA, POBLACION FROM tclientes WHERE POBLACION='?';");
            ps.setString(1, "MADRID");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("CODIGOCLIENTE")+" "+rs.getString("EMPRESA")+" "+rs.getString("POBLACION"));
            }

            conexion.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values
>   was 
>           'MADRID')  Query - conn:8(M)  - "SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA, POBLACION FROM 
>           tclientes WHERE POBLACION='?';"
>         at 
>           org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getSqlException(ExceptionMapper.java:192)
>         at   org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.setParameter(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:435)
>         at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePrepareStatement.setString(BasePrepareStatement.java:1379)
>         at Conexion.mainPruebas.main(mainPruebas.java:22)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the quotation marks around the question mark in your `PreparedStatement`

```
ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA, POBLACION FROM tclientes WHERE POBLACION=?;");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! What a shame, it was something very simple

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE
`ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA, POBLACION FROM tclientes WHERE POBLACION='?';")`
WITH
`ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT CODIGOCLIENTE, EMPRESA, POBLACION FROM tclientes WHERE POBLACION=?;")`

NOTICE: I have removed the `''` around `?`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! What a shame, it was something very simple